# Is there any Kafka Monitoring API in Java?

Tags: java, message-queue, apache-kafka, broker

I am trying to write a Java code to get consumer offsets and lag for
our kafka cluster.
Is there a Java API to get this information ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get this info if you use Kafka Client libraries and their APIs.  That said, there are tools that can give you this info and a lot more if you are after Kafka metrics/monitoring.  [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) from Linkedin and [SPM for Kafka](https://sematext.com/spm/integrations/kafka-monitoring/) from Sematext are two good ones to look at.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Java Management Extensions (**JMX**) to monitor your **KAFKA**.
Kafka already has inbuilt JMX, you just need to enable it -

In the kafka setup, edit “**kafka-run-class.sh**” script file by adding the following line to it:

> KAFKA_JMX_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false "

Also, edit the “kafka-server-start.sh” script file present in the kafka setup to set the JMX port to 9999 by adding the following line:

> export JMX_PORT=${JMX_PORT:-9999}

Comment: tnx, but i like to have a beautiful API

Comment: Use Ganglia on top of it. You will get all the metrics which you wish to see.

Answer (score 0):

You should find what you need in this project: https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/storm/kafka

There you can see the *kafka.javaapi.consumer.SimpleConsumer* and how it's being used. Use Maven to pull all the dependencies from the Maven repo and you should see a **kafka_2.10-0.8.2.1.jar** file that provides the Kafka API calls that you need.

The github project referenced above should give you extra pointers on how the API is used.

Comment: Unfortunately,  SimpleConsumer let me to know offset fro one client not all consumers on on topic. I need all offsets. in addition it present nothing regarding lag. However, i need this API  at Producer side not Consumer side.

Comment: @user3359139 the same API has the package package kafka.producer which has all you need for Producer and Consumer classes.

Comment: OK, then let me know the API that gives lag size for a topic and consumer group...

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,there is an application which **write in java** to track the offsets for all the consumer groups in a Kafka cluster.You can get the result in Json or html, you can also configure the app to push the offset metrics at a regular interval to a StatsD server.

**here is the project:**

https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-monitoring-tool

**the monitor result :**

[image]

Comment: This link is dead and not updated even on Symantec's page! Is it not in use?

Answer (score -1):

The offsets of group are stored in zookeeper, you need a zookeeper instance,a nd then use the method `zk.getChildren(path,false)` to get node info and use method `zk.getData(path,false,null)` to get the offset info.

Set `path="/consumers"` you can get the consumers group list.

Set `path="/consumers/xxx group/offset/xxx topic/xxx partition"` you can get the offset.